# How to launch App on LG webOS based Pro:Centric Device

Tags: lg, smart-tv

I am developing applications for various Smart TV platforms and the client is asking about LG Pro:Centric device. Is there anyone who can help me launch the app on Pro:Centric platform. Please refer to proper guidance or authentic links.

Suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Steps to setup Pro:Centric TV

1. Turn on TV and press and hold settings button until you see channel popup/message popup.
2. Immediately type 1105 and press OK.
3. Secret settings menu will open.
4. Then turn ON Hotel mode
5. Check if you are connected to internet in Network Settings
6. Open Pro:Centric option and set mode to HTML and media type to IP or Domain address according to your need and fill out input box. Eg put ip to local server which will contain xait.xml file which contains app url and fill port number to 80.
7. Enable "Native EPG" and "Receive Data"

Steps to setup server

1. Create xait.xml file inside procentric/application inside root hosted folder(Note: IP of this server is to be used while entering IP in Pro:Centric menu in TV)
2. Structure of XAIT file

   `<XAIT>
       <versionNumber>1</versionNumber>
       <AbstractService>
           <svcName>Pro:Centric Application</svcName>
           <svcId>0x1204</svcId>
           <isAutoSelect>True</isAutoSelect>
           <ApplicationList>
               <Application>
                   <appName>Demo</appName>
                   <applicationIdentifier>
                       <orgId>1</orgId>
                       <appId>1</appId>
                   </applicationIdentifier>
                   <applicationDescriptor>
                       <type>Hcap-h</type>
                       <controlCode>AUTOSTART</controlCode>
                       <visibility>NOT_VISIBLE_USERS</visibility>
                       <priority>255</priority>
                       <version>1</version>
                   </applicationDescriptor>
                   <HcapDescriptor>
                       <url>URL_OF_HOSTED_APP_GOES_HERE</url>
                   </HcapDescriptor>
               </Application>
           </ApplicationList>
       </AbstractService>
   </XAIT>`
3. Restart your TV and wait for app to launch.